# Slice Alphanumeric word from column sentence using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to slice only alphanumeric word from column sentence using pyspark.

For Example,

Original text:

[image]

Expected results:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please extract text between the white space.

```
df.withColumn('newtext', F.regexp_extract('text','\s(.*?)\s',0)).show()

+---+----------------+-------+
| id|            text|newtext|
+---+----------------+-------+
|  1|ABCD AB12C BCDEF| AB12C |
+---+----------------+-------+
```

Followingg your revised question. Extract as ordered;

```
df.withColumn('newtext', F.regexp_extract('text','([A-Za-z]+\d+[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\d+|\d+[A-Za-z]+)',0)).show()

+---+------------------+-------+
| id|              text|newtext|
+---+------------------+-------+
|  1|  ABCD AB12C BCDEF|  AB12C|
|  2|SE2DC WERDF EWSQSA|  SE2DC|
|  3| REDC SEDX WSDR12 | WSDR12|
+---+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks and it is working...also I have updated my queries above...can you pls help me on that.

Comment: thank you for the response. At the same time how to check whether identified alphanumeric word length should be greater than 3.